# Changing sprite to image in processing

Tags: java, image, sprite, processing

I am using binary digits to create an enemy and now I looking to replace it with an image  however I keep getting errors when I try and replace the sprite data to an image data as their are too many lines of code to take into consideration when changing the data. I have included how I created my sprite and what I am trying to do to change it to an image, and what error I keep getting:

This is how I drew my sprite:

```
class Enemy extends SpaceShip {  
  Enemy(int xpos, int ypos) {
    x = xpos;
    y = ypos;
    sprite    = new String[5];
    sprite[0] = "1011101";
    sprite[1] = "0101010";
    sprite[2] = "1111111";
    sprite[3] = "0101010";
    sprite[4] = "1000001";
  }                         

  PImage img;  

  img = loadImage("image.png");
  }

  void draw() {
    image(img, x, y);
  }
```

The error I am getting is that although the sprite does get replaced it is not moving how the sprite was and is not the correct size either.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can run. Note that this should not be your whole sketch, just an example. For example, if you're just asking about displaying an image, then we don't need any code for moving the player or shooting bullets. Also, please post the exact text of any errors you're getting. Include screenshots if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet you posted is a bit confusing.
Firstly, the syntax isn't quite right, perhaps you meant something like this:

```
class Enemy extends SpaceShip {  
  PImage img;

  Enemy(int xpos, int ypos) {
    x = xpos;
    y = ypos;
    //assuming sprite is inherited from SpaceShip ?
    sprite    = new String[5];
    sprite[0] = "1011101";
    sprite[1] = "0101010";
    sprite[2] = "1111111";
    sprite[3] = "0101010";
    sprite[4] = "1000001";
    //you are loading an image, but I see no use of the sprite
    img = loadImage("image.png");
  }

  void draw() {
    image(img, x, y);
  }

}
```

It's unclear why you're loading a separate image when you want to display the binary string pattern as an image. If I understand correctly, you want to convert the binary string representation to a PImage.

You can directly access the PImage's `pixels`, so you could directly write your image like this:

```
PImage sprite = new PImage(7,5,RGB);
sprite.pixels = new int[]{color(255),color( 0 ),color(255),color(255),color(255),color( 0 ),color(255),
                          color( 0 ),color(255),color( 0 ),color(255),color( 0 ),color(255),color( 0 ),
                          color(255),color(255),color(255),color(255),color(255),color(255),color(255),
                          color( 0 ),color(255),color( 0 ),color(255),color( 0 ),color(255),color( 0 ),
                          color(255),color( 0 ),color( 0 ),color( 0 ),color( 0 ),color( 0 ),color(255)};

sprite.updatePixels();

noSmooth();
image(sprite,0,0,70,50);
```

Notice `color(255)` is used where you'd expect 1 and `color(0)` is where you'd expect 0.

Alternatively, you can traverse the `String[]` and each character of each row to set pixels of an PImage:

```
PImage fromBinaryStrings(String[] sprite){

  int h = sprite.length;
  int w = sprite[0].length();

  PImage result = new PImage(w,h,RGB);

  for(int y = 0 ; y < h; y++){
    String row = sprite[y];
    for(int x = 0; x < w; x++){
      if(row.charAt(x) == '1'){
        result.set(x,y,color(255));
      }else{
        result.set(x,y,color(0));
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Basic demo:

```
void setup(){
  noSmooth();
  scale(10);

  Enemy e = new Enemy(0,0);
  e.draw();
}

PImage fromBinaryStrings(String[] sprite){
  //determine height: number of lines
  int h = sprite.length;
  //determine width: length of a line
  int w = sprite[0].length();
  //create an image
  PImage result = new PImage(w,h,RGB);
  //traverse rows
  for(int y = 0 ; y < h; y++){
    //access row string
    String row = sprite[y];
    //traverse cols
    for(int x = 0; x < w; x++){
      //check each char's value and set the color accordingly
      if(row.charAt(x) == '1'){
        result.set(x,y,color(255));
      }else{
        result.set(x,y,color(0));
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
class SpaceShip{
  int x,y;
  String[] sprite;
}
class Enemy extends SpaceShip {  
  PImage img;

  Enemy(int xpos, int ypos) {
    x = xpos;
    y = ypos;

    sprite    = new String[5];
    sprite[0] = "1011101";
    sprite[1] = "0101010";
    sprite[2] = "1111111";
    sprite[3] = "0101010";
    sprite[4] = "1000001";

    img = fromBinaryStrings(sprite);
  }

  void draw() {
    image(img, x, y);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I figured out another way to solve the problem. I simply deleted the sprite data and made new code which allowed me to call the image straight away.